# How to fix invalid url error using UrlfetchApp?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I have a scheduled report that comes to my Gmail inbox as a download link. I need to figure out how to download the data and add it to Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I've set up the script to pull the data from Gmail:

```
function getDownloadLink() {
  
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('test')
  var threads = label.getThreads()
  
  for(var t in threads) {
    var messages = threads[t].getMessages()
    
    for(var i in messages) {
      var data = messages[i].getPlainBody()
      var regExp = new RegExp('[\n\r].*Download:\s*([^\n\r]*)')
      var link = regExp.exec(data)[1]
      
      return link
    }
  }
}
```

Next, based on some google searches, I tried to use the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` method to get the data from the link but was unable to do so. I got an error related to the URL not being a valid URL. My guess is that I'm not using the regex function correctly to extract the URL *(I found the regex expression online and it seemed to work on regex101.com)*

This is the data that's stored in `var data`:

```
[20-08-09 11:28:08:054 PDT] The Amazon Advertising report you requested is now available.

If you no longer need this report to be generated or if you do not need it to be generated as often, please update or delete your subscription.  To manage your report subscriptions, access the Amazon Advertising Report Center.
* Note, you will need to sign into your account before accessing Amazon Advertising.

Report name: SP KW - July&#x27;20 XXXXXX
Generated on: Sunday, 9 August, 2020
* This download link expires on Sunday, 16 August, 2020

Download: https://corvo-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/TRESAH/2020-08-09/f1a86607-1558-427b-8976-370438ceb182%402020-08-09%2017%3A19%3A00.0/SP%20KW%20-%20July%2720%20XXXXX%20XXXXXX.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200809T172556Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAY2R3XYZC46Q4PK5E%2F20200809%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=bde1f7039b4a005a6f531129183eed553e88c50999999152cca827bbe1838b
```

I've distorted the link slightly as its confidential data but that is essentially the format of the email. The link downloads a .xlsx file. How to get the data from the link in the mail body and then get the data into a Google Sheet?

Comment: Log the `link` variable and see if you can access the link from the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your `regExp` and `var data` of sample data, I think that in your case, the retrieved URL is like  `https://corvo-reports.s3.amazonaws.com...`. The 1st character has a space.

- `regExp` of `var regExp = new RegExp('[\n\r].*Download:\s*([^\n\r]*)')` is `/[\n\r].*Download:s*([^\n\r]*)/`

I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('[\n\r].*Download:\s*([^\n\r]*)')
```

#### To:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('[\n\r].*Download:\\s*([^\n\r]*)');
```

- By this modification, `https://corvo-reports.s3.amazonaws.com...` can be retrieved from the sample data.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether your URL of `https://corvo-reports.s3.amazonaws.com...` is valid. So if the URL cannot be used, please confirm the URL again.
- Also, when above modification cannot be used, please try `var link = regExp.exec(data)[1].trim()` instead of `var link = regExp.exec(data)[1]`.

#### Reference:

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thank you for your help! You were right, the issue was with the empty space that was in front of the URL :)